# RoR: How to retrieve individual attributes of a relationship or collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to list users I am following

My models:

```
Relationship.rb

belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"

User.rb

has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

In my view

```
<%= current_user.followers.collect { |follower| follower.username } %>
```

This gives in view:

```
Following
["Lisa", nil, "Derek"] etc
```

How can I list these users normally in my view like this?

```
Lisa
Derek
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, of course, on how you want it to be displayed. But it's quite easy, for example, assuming you're using `erb` for rendering, you can do it with an iteration:

```
<% current_user.followers.pluck(:username).compact.each do |follower_username| %>
  <%= follower_username %>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

Note that I used AR `pluck` instead of `map`, which is slightly more effective and more idiomatic in Rails world, and I used `compact` to rule out `nil` values.

Comment: That's great, thanks! <%= usename %> did not work but I used <%= follower_username %> and that worked :)

Comment: Obviously, my mistake. ;)